# dpkg install environment

Tags: apt, development, dpkg

I'm trying to creat a .deb that, as part of its installation process, pings an external server.

So I have an install_foobar script which does the install.

However, I can't get install_foobar to `curl` out to the server, or, for that matter, echo out to /tmp.

What is the environment that is created? I am wondering if its some sort of pbuilder-esque world that is removed after the install finishes...

Comment: Paul, you need to clarify here. There are preinstall, and postinstall scripts that run.. Where is install_foobar script running? How did you package it? I suggest reading this page, specifically section 7.6: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.html

Comment: @balloons: I haven't the faintest idea. I was handed the package and I'm working on getting it working correctly. I can assure you I've read the debian guide cover to cover and I have not found illumination in it.  I'm building it with dpkg-buildpackage. The rules file is the %: dh $@ rules.

Comment: If this is an open source package, you might get a bit more help if you link out or otherwise include the package info. I'm afraid I can't give you anymore info as-is -- it's too vague for me at least to follow what your trying to do. Sorry mate :-(

Comment: @balloons: I am sorry too! This is an in-house package. One of my colleagues says that dpkg -i executes in a sort of chroot environment.

Comment: @PaulNathan Does the package have any postinstall or preinstall scripts in the debian/ folder, if so, what are the contents of them?

Comment: @arand: no, it did not! (at least, no files with that name)

Comment: Hmm, so is the install_foobar script run in the build process in debian/rules, are the contents of d/rules more than what you've already posted? Afaik, maintainer scripts or d/rules are the only files that could actually execute this script... Note also that anything run in d/rules will only run during the build process, not during installation of the package.

Comment: You're right, on installation or removal of a package, that's the only time those scripts will get run (preinst, postinst, prerm, postrm). And debian/rules will only get run at build time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform any actions besides unpacking files at install/remove time you will need to make use of [package maintainer scripts](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html)

(Note, "pinging home" is often seen as somewhat dubious practice by software if done without the consent of the user, though seeing as this is an in-house package, I guess that's not really an issue).

A rough example would be using a packagename.postinst something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for #PACKAGE#
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postinst> `configure' <most-recently-configured-version>
#        * <old-postinst> `abort-upgrade' <new version>
#        * <conflictor's-postinst> `abort-remove' `in-favour' <package>
#          <new-version>
#        * <postinst> `abort-remove'
#        * <deconfigured's-postinst> `abort-deconfigure' `in-favour'
#          <failed-install-package> <version> `removing'
#          <conflicting-package> <version>
# for details, see http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package


case "$1" in
    configure)
    ping server.net # ADD ACTIONS HERE
    echo foo > /tmp/foo # ETC.
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.

#DEBHELPER#

exit 0
```

Obviously you'd need a corresponding removal in the pre/postrm scripts if you added any permanent files in the pre/postinstall scripts.

Templates for preinst, postinst, prerm and postrm scripts are available via the dh-make package, in the files

```
 /usr/share/debhelper/dh_make/debian/*.ex
```